# Should I connect to SQL directly or use web services for a commercial tablet app

Tags: sql, entity-framework, web-services

I have a requirement to create a tablet application for use in restaurants.  It will all be on a private internal network so security is not an issue.  The question is which will cause the least network traffic?  I can either connect directly to SQL using entity framework or I can connect to web services I create on the SQL server in IIS and the tablets communicate with that.

I guess to simplify it, does a standard SQL connection transfer more data than is necessary?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a general rule, as network architecture plays into the answer quite heavily.

As a general guideline i would suggest to make web services or php "interfaces" on the server, it would give you a easier and more controllable data flow, besides you could handle transactions easier, as all of them would go thorugh one interface, all db accesses coming from one machine. It makes also debugging and errorhandling easier (log the interface and you see everything that's happening, so you don't ahve to check logs on devices) than if every client connects directly to the DB, gives you more control.

Just a general suggestion, a kind of web services/interface or whatsoever is always worth the investment, sooner or later you will go anyway this direction.

My humble oppinion